# VBA Excel Loop not picking up all matches

Tags: excel, vba

I have an excel routine which is designed to Blueprint examination questions against competencies. The routine loops through competencies on the first sheet and looks for the same competencies (expressed as strings e.g. '3.2.3') in other sheets.  When it finds the competency on another sheets it writes the name of the sheet, exam question and marks awarded in a cell.  The routine also sums the marks allocated to a competency and writes the 'marks per competency/total marks' to another cell.

However, the routine does not pick up questions allocated to some competencies.  If I change the competency for these questions they are mapped correctly.  The obvious issue is that the competencies on the sheets are not the same. This is not the case as I have copied and pasted to check. I have tried numerous strategies including ensuring the competencies on both pages are strings.
Does any one have any ideas? what the problem might be.

This is my coding

```
Private Sub Command_MapComp_Click()
    
    Dim BP As Worksheet: Set BP = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Blue Print")
    Dim CF As Worksheet: Set CF = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Competency Framework")
    Dim PM As Worksheet: Set PM = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Preliminary Mapping")
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim lr As Long
    Dim lc As Long
    Dim i As Long
    Dim j As Long
    Dim FindVal As String
    Dim Comp As String
    Dim Total As Long
    Dim AllQuest As Long
    
    AllQuest = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Paper 1").Cells("5", "H").Value +  _
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Paper 2").Cells("5", "H").Value _
    + ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Paper 3").Cells("5", "H").Value + _
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Oral").Cells("5", "H").Value
    
    'Clear  prior mapping
        BP.Range("G13:AU29").ClearContents
        BP.Range("E13:E29").ClearContents
        
    'Loop through each cell in Column 'F' from row 13 to 29
    'and store its value in the 'findVal' variable
    For i = 13 To 29
      Total = 0
        FindVal = CStr(BP.Cells(i, "F").Value)
     
     For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
            If ws.Name = BP.Name Or ws.Name = CF.Name Or ws.Name = PM.Name Then
                'Do nothing
            Else
  
        'Locate the last empty cell in row 'irow':
        lc = BP.Cells(i, BP.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column + 1
        'Loop each sheet in the workbook
       
                'Loop each cell in WS Column 'B' in the worksheet from Row 8
                'to the last row to find the value of the 'FindVal' variable
                lr = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
               
                For j = 8 To lr
                
                    Comp = CStr(ws.Cells(j, "B").Value)
                     
                    If Comp = FindVal Then
                    'Write the name of the worksheet in the first empty cell in row 'i'
                       
                       BP.Cells(i, lc) = ws.Name & vbNewLine & CStr(ws.Cells(j, "A")) _
                        & vbNewLine & CStr(ws.Cells(j, "H")) & " Marks"
                        BP.Cells(i, lc).HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
                        BP.Cells(i, lc).VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
                        
                        lc = lc + 1
                         Total = Total + ws.Cells(j, "H").Value
                        'Exit For ' it's been found, no need to loop anymore
                    End If
                Next j
                'Write marks per competency per paper
                
                BP.Cells(i, "E").Value = Total & "/" & AllQuest
              End If
         Next ws
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Try `FindVal = Trim(BP.Cells(i, "F").Value)` and `Comp = Trim(ws.Cells(j, "B").Value)` to eliminate any leading or traililng spaces.

Comment: You can also try to compare with lowercase `If lcase(Comp) = lcase(FindVal) Then`

Comment: can you provide examples of the ones that are not found and of the ones that are found.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.  Neither of the first two suggestions worked.  This is an example of what I am getting.                                                                        Competencies 1.1.3, 1.2.3 1.3.3 and 1.4.3 Map.  1.5.3 does not.                          2.2.1 Maps but 2.2.3does not, 2.2.3 does  etc

Comment: Error was in the looping